# Using ASP.NET Identity in an ASP.NET Core MVC application without Entity Framework and Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Is it possible to use ASP.NET Identity without Entity Framework and Entity Framework migrations? The rest of my application will be using a Micro ORM for data access. However, the application is using the built in ASP.NET Identity Individual User accounts.

My goal is to still be able to use the built in UserManager and LoginManager classes and additionally retrieve a list of the Users using the Micro ORM and do away with anything to do with EF/Migrations. Is this possible? It doesn't seem like it is since the original database structure is created by Applying the initial migration.

If someone has a good technique for doing this, please share.

Comment: @johnny5 So it seems like it isn't worth it. I guess I will just keep the AspNetIdentity stuff using ApplicationDbContext and Migrations and everything else using the Micro ORM. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've Been hosting a token server and been authenticating though that You can Check out Identity Server 4, it might be overkill but it abstracts the login process

Comment: @johnny5 I am using IdentityServer4 w/ ASP.NET Identity. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity. This project uses EF and Migrations... How could I do without it?

Comment: Use Identity Server 4 with EF as it's own self contained service.  The rest of your services use the other orm,  but this project will use EF

Comment: @johnny5 I have a Data class library that uses a micro orm for all of the data calls. Identity Server uses EF and migrations for the AspNetUser tables. Is there anyway I can clean this up? I see I believe what you are saying is think of it as IdentityServer is using EF / Migrations but the rest of my application is not correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147405/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-johnny-5).

Comment: @johnny5: Overriding `UserManager` interfaces is non-sense (and it's a concrete class). All you need to do is implement the store(s) yourself, typically user store and role store

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to create a custom user Store:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser>,
                         IUserClaimStore<IdentityUser>,
                         IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>,
                         IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>,
                         IUserPasswordStore<IdentityUser>,
                         IUserSecurityStampStore<IdentityUser>
{
    // interface implementations not shown
}
```

Then you need to register it into the dependency injection container:

```
// Add identity types
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Identity Services
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, CustomRoleStore>();
```

This is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers).

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net Identity has abstracted away the stores it needs and documentation on their stores is here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers

This is an example of a store;

```
public class InMemoryUserStore<TUser> :
        IUserStore<TUser>,
        IUserLoginStore<TUser>,
        IUserClaimStore<TUser>,
        IUserPasswordStore<TUser>,
        IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>,
        IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>,
        IUserEmailStore<TUser>,
        IUserLockoutStore<TUser>,
        IUserAuthenticatorKeyStore<TUser>,
        IUserTwoFactorRecoveryCodeStore<TUser>,
        IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser> where TUser: MemoryIdentityUser
    {
        ...
    }
```

You can also have your own User object, and it doesn't have to inherit from anything.

```
public class MemoryIdentityUser
{
    private List<MemoryUserClaim> _claims;
    private List<MemoryUserLogin> _logins;
    private List<MemoryUserToken> _tokens;
    ...
}
```

Asp.Net Identity is an engine and as such is opinionated.  It is that opinion that drove the abstractions of the stores.  I wish the Asp.Net Identity docs has full sequence diagrams as to how it interacts with the stores.  At a minimum a few reference sequences that have to be honored.

The store has some quirks where it has required methods that are only to mutate private data in the implementation and then followed up by update calls that assume you will commit that data to persistent storage.

You might want to check out this project;
https://github.com/ghstahl/AspNetCore.2.InMemoryIdentity

You can see what you need to do without the burden of having a database.

Hooking it up;

```
// My user is custom, so I made ApplicationUser inherit
public class ApplicationUser : MemoryIdentityUser
{
}
```

Startup.cs;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddSingleton<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(provider =>
  {
    return new InMemoryUserStore<ApplicationUser>();
  });
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>(Configuration)
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  // Add application services.
  services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

  services.AddMvc();
}
```

In AddIdentity, the following illustrates to the extent you can bring in your own implementations

```
public static class InMemoryIdentityServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        where TUser : class => services.AddIdentity<TUser>(configuration,null);

    public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration,Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
        where TUser : class
    {
        // Services used by identity
        var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
                };
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme,
                o => o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme)
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            });

        // Hosting doesn't add IHttpContextAccessor by default
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        // Identity services
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();

        // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
        services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>, AspNetUserManager<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>, SignInManager<TUser>>();

        if (setupAction != null)
        {
            services.Configure(setupAction);
        }

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), services);
    }
}
```

There are a bunch of IUserStore implementations out there, with every type of backing database.  I copied my InMemoryUserStore from another project that was using MongoDB as a backing DB.

Comment: Link-Only answers are discouraged.  Could you flesh out your answer a bit more, giving some examples of how to use what you linked to, or explaining it more in-depth please?